# How can i create a dashboard?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, dashboard

I create an app that have a UITabBar with four tab and each one has a UINavigationController. one of these UIViewController is the Home screen that has several buttons and these buttons push to these UIViewController, if this UIViewController pushed belong to one of them, we select the tab by keeping the same UINavigationController of the Home Screen (to let the user back to the home screen(UIBarButton in the navbar)). 
How can i do that without using any framework?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you asking how to make one of your buttons (such as the "Actualités" button) go to a different tab?

If that's what you want to do, you need to connect the button to an IBAction in its view controller.  The IBAction should do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)accueilButtonWasTouched:(id)sender {
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

If that is not what you mean, please try to explain your question in more detail.

### Update

Based on your comments, I think I understand what you want.  You want a global navigation stack.  When the user changes tabs *or* navigates to a new view in the same tab, you want to push the new view onto the global navigation stack.  You want the back button in the navigation bar to go back to the previous view, which is sometimes a different tab, and sometimes a different view in the same tab.

Doing this is complicated. You need to keep a global stack of the user's actions.  When you switch tabs, you need to push an item on the stack that records the previous tab.  When the user navigates to a new view in a tab, you need to push an item on the stack that indicates that a view was pushed.  When the user touches the back button in any of the tabs, you need to pop the top item of the global stack and take action (switch tabs or ask the current tab's navigation controller to pop a view controller) based on the popped item.

Comment: but how can i keep the same UINavigationController to let the user return to the previous view (back button in the navbar)?

Comment: Do you want the back button to change to the previous tab?

Comment: This is a Q&A site.  It's not a "write my program for me" site.  What you want to do is complicated.  If you don't know how to get started, you need to practice on simpler problems.

Comment: No i didn't say write my program for me it's just to be more explicative :) i say a peace of code